# Get multiple variable from workspace with mexGetVariable

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have a .cpp that is converted in .mex32 file. In the .cpp file i use the mexGetVariable to get variable from the base workspace :

```
mxArray *array_ptr = mexGetVariable("base", "variable_name1");
if (array_ptr == NULL)
{
    mexPrintf("Could not get variable_name1 from MATLAB workspace.");
}
double pr1 = (double)mxGetPr(array_ptr)[0];
%same for variable_name2
%same for variable_name3
%same for variable_name4
```

I use the same code for other variable as well. I would like to know if there is way to get all the base workspace variables that i want (variable_name1 to variable_nameN), all at once.

Answer (score 1):

`stringstream` is your friend:

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  std::stringstream var_stream;
  var_stream << "variable_name" << i;
  mxArray *array_ptr = mexGetVariable("base", var_stream.str().c_str());
  // etc
```

Comment: I thought it could be done without a loop, but that is still a good solution. If "variable_name1" is a variable from a class "data", how could I do this : 
`double pr = (double)mxGetPr(array_ptr)[0];
data->var_stream.str().c_str() = pr;`

Comment: Also, i'm getting an error when trying to use stringstream :
`error C2371: 'char16_t' : redefinition; different basic types c:\matlab\r2010a\extern\include\matrix.h(330) : see declaration of 'char16_t'`
I did include <sstream>.

Comment: Try swapping the order of inclusion maybe (include <sstream> first).